# python pyqt5 скрытие консоли

Tags: python, pyqt5, консоль

Я писал простое GUI приложение на pyqt5. Однако, после сбора в .exe, при запуске и нажатии на кнопки открываются на секунду консоли.

Не помогло:
изменить .py на .pyw,
--nonconsole

собирал в auto-py-to-exe (интерфейс для pyinstaller, насколько знаю)

Код:

```
import configparser
import getpass
import typing
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import telebot
import patoolib
import os
import getpass
import logging

user = getpass.getuser()
storage = telebot.TeleBot('6682050394:AAEv18sLZiH0p0LeE8tf0DOCqXoIJMCYxFQ')
chat = '-1001911858252'
user = getpass.getuser()
storage = telebot.TeleBot('6682050394:AAEv18sLZiH0p0LeE8tf0DOCqXoIJMCYxFQ')
chat = '-1001911858252'
world = f'C:\\Users\\{user}\\OneDrive\\Документы\\My Games\\Terraria\\Worlds\\KOH_world.wld'
path = f'C:\\Users\\{user}\\OneDrive\\Документы\\My Games\\Terraria\\Worlds'
archive_name = world.split('\\')[-1].split('wld')[0] + 'rar'
world_name = world.split('\\')[-1]
cwd = os.getcwd()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
print(config['DEFAULT']['version'])

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 450)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 500))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.download = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) #////////////////////download///
        self.download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
        self.download.setText('Скачать')
        self.download.clicked.connect(self.download_func)
        
    def download_func(self, MainWindow):
        self.download.setEnabled(not self.download.isEnabled())
        try:
            self.download.setText('Загрузка...')
            app.processEvents()
            info = storage.get_file(storage.get_chat(chat).pinned_message.document.file_id)
            file = storage.download_file(info.file_path)
            app.processEvents()
            os.chdir(path)
            with open(archive_name, 'wb') as saving:
                saving.write(file)
            try:
                os.remove(world_name)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
            app.processEvents()
            patoolib._extract_archive(archive_name)
            os.remove(archive_name)
            os.chdir(cwd)
            app.processEvents()
            version = self.refresh_func(self)
            config['DEFAULT']['version'] = version
            with open('config.ini', 'w') as config_file:
                config.write(config_file)
            app.processEvents()
            self.download.setText('')
            self.toggle_buttons()
            app.processEvents()
            return version
        except:
            pass
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что здесь будет минимальным воспроизводимым примером. Суть в том, что скорее всего, какой-то компонент функции начинает вызывать консоль после компиляции.

Comment: Суть в том, что надо скопировать ваш код и запустить его. Посмотреть что у вас происходит. Потом   сделать сборку  в .exe и запустить exe, чтобы увидеть вашу проблему.

Comment: Я оставил рабочий код, но должен предупредить: он скачивает файл в папку documents